# realtime push notifications in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to create an android app for my college. I would like to update the users with the latest news which is posted in the website. I came to know that we can parse the website content to the android app. 
 I would like to know if it is possible for me to trigger a push notification to the users once any news gets updated in the website???**Give me a source where i can learn about this**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to trigger a push notification to the users once any news gets updated in the website .Please share your problem more specically so that I can answer you in detail.

Comment: can you you give me any reference site through I can learn how to do it.

Comment: For json parsing :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ and for Xml parsing : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/